# How can i get the last user who created the last topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i have 3 models as shown below. In my categories/index.erb.haml I have all the categories showing. I have a column that i want to show the latest topic that a user created and their name as well. I have an example below.

```
Category
  has_many :topics
Topic
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
User
  has_many :topics

.categories
- @categories.each do |category|
    .container
        .row
            .col-md-6
                .col-md-3
                    .img
                        = image_tag('first.png')
                .col-md-9
                    %h4.category.name
                        = link_to category.name, category_path(category)
                    %p
                        = category.description
            .col-md-2
                .topic-count
                    %h1
                        = category.topics.count
                .topics
                    Topics
            .col-md-4
                .description
                    %p
                        Last topic by 'user name here' Tue Nov 28, 2015
                        'topic title here'
```

Comment: how about `Topic.last.user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the last `Topic` for each `Category` than you have to loop through the `Categories` and get the last `Topic` since you have a relation.

```
Category.includes(:topics).find_each do |category|
  last_topic_of_the_category = category.topics.last  # <= The last topic
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the associations you posted, you should be able to get the user of the last topic by this:

```
Topic.last.user
```

Also, mentioned by @marczking in the comment section.

`Topic.last` will give you the last topic that was created and then `Topic.last.user` will give you the corresponding user as your `Topic` model *belongs_to* a `User`. In order to make this work, you also need to have a `user_id` column in the `topics` table in the database.

Comment: That works for the last topic that was created. But what if i want to get the last topic created for each specific category? In that page Im showing all the categories in columns. Each one should have a different topic title.

Comment: For a particular category, you can do: `category.topics.last`. You can also do: `Topic.where(category_id: category.id).last`. Both will work.

Comment: Topic.where(category: ...).last.user